# How to get parent QGraphicsItem pixmap with respect to child rectangle area?

Tags: qt

I have created a QGraphicsRectItem and on top of that another small QGraphicsRectItem is placed as child. I can move the child item on top of the parent item through mouse.  I need to get the parent item's QPixmap below the child rectangle area so that I can apply my custom blur algorithm to it and render to child item.  Finally, I am moving the child item on top of the parent and I can see the blured parent area.  So is there any way to get the parent's QPixmap area from the child item with respective to child position ?

Comment: [`QGraphicsRectItem::rect()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsrectitem.html#rect) should return the child item's rectangle relative to that of its parent.  Or is that not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: getting the position of the child relative to the parent position is certainly feasible (see G.M. comment). And once you get that, you just have to invert it.

If the top left corner of the child is at coordinates (x, y) relative to the parent, then the top left corner of the parent is at coordinates (-x, -y) relative to the child.